# zlib compress and uncompress usage

Tags: c, zlib, compression

I am trying to compress and decompress the simplest way a random generated string with zlib using `compress()` and `uncompress()` functions. But after executing the `uncompress()` function I get an `Z_DATA_ERROR (-3)`. Does somebody know where my error is ?

Here is the code :

```
int
main(int argc __attribute ((unused)),char **argv __attribute ((unused)))
{
    unsigned char* cara_in;
    unsigned char* cara_inter;
    unsigned char* cara_out; 

    size_t i;
    size_t len = 1024*50; //50 KBytes
    int ret;

    cara_in = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*)*len);
    cara_inter = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*)*len);
    cara_out = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*)*len);

    uLongf size_cara_inter;
    uLongf size_cara_out;

    srand(time (NULL));

    /* Generating */
    for(i=0; i < len-1;i++)
    {
        cara_in[i] = (int)(rand() %24 +65);
    }

    size_cara_inter = 2*len;

    ret = compress(
                cara_inter,
                &size_cara_inter,
                cara_in,
                (uLongf)strlen((const char*)cara_in)
                );
    if(ret != Z_OK)
    {
        /* error */
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_cara_out = 2*len;

    ret = uncompress(
                cara_out,
                &size_cara_out,
                cara_inter,
                (uLongf)strlen((const char*)cara_inter)
                );
    if(ret != Z_OK)
    {
        /* error */
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* compare */
    ret = strcmp((const char*)cara_in, (const char*)cara_out);
    if(ret != 0){
        /*problem*/
        fprintf(stderr, "\nOuups! :(\nResult of cmp is %d", ret);
        fflush(stderr);

        fprintf(
                    stderr,
                    "\ncara_in length : %d, cara_out length : %d\n",
                    (unsigned)strlen((const char*)cara_in), (unsigned)strlen((const char*)cara_out)
                    );
        fflush(stderr);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Is your compiler somehow not telling you about the argument type mismatches in your `compress()` and `decompress()` calls?  In that case, turn up the warning levels.  If it *is* telling you, then don't you think the compilation warnings might be related to the runtime failure?

Comment: Ouups, yes ! I have corrected the warnings but it's still not working ...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Gaston Lagaffe! A potential reason for the failure is that the null terminating character is allocated, but never set to 0. So `strlen(cara_in)` is undefined behavior. It's called a "gaffe" in french...

Comment: Well, only a french could guess that the drawing was Gaston Lagaffe ... :)

Comment: And yes it's working ! so simple .... thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here is the corrected source code, thanks to Francis :

```
int
main(int argc __attribute ((unused)),char **argv __attribute ((unused)))
{
    unsigned char* cara_in;
    unsigned char* cara_inter;
    unsigned char* cara_out; 

    size_t i;
    size_t len = 1024*50; //50 KBytes
    int ret;

    cara_in = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*)*len);
    cara_inter = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*)*len);
    cara_out = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*)*len);

    uLongf size_cara_inter;
    uLongf size_cara_out;

    srand(time (NULL));

    /* Generating */
    for(i=0; i < len-1;i++)
    {
        cara_in[i] = (int)(rand() %24 +65);
    }

    cara_in[len] = '\0';

    size_cara_inter = 2*len;

    ret = compress(
                cara_inter,
                &size_cara_inter,
                cara_in,
                (uLongf)strlen((const char*)cara_in)
                );
    if(ret != Z_OK)
    {
        /* error */
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_cara_out = 2*len;

    ret = uncompress(
                cara_out,
                &size_cara_out,
                cara_inter,
                size_cara_inter
                );
    if(ret != Z_OK)
    {
        /* error */
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* compare */
    ret = strcmp((const char*)cara_in, (const char*)cara_out);
    if(ret != 0){
        /*problem*/
        fprintf(stderr, "\nOuups! :(\nResult of cmp is %d", ret);
        fflush(stderr);

        fprintf(
                    stderr,
                    "\ncara_in length : %d, cara_out length : %d\n",
                    (unsigned)strlen((const char*)cara_in), (unsigned)strlen((const char*)cara_out)
                    );
        fflush(stderr);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```